# visionkit DataScannerViewController poor accuracy after iOS 17 update

Tags: swift, ios17, visionkit

I created an iPhone app that uses the DataScannerViewController to recognise passports and ID cards. It had been working perfectly with good accuracy.

After some time, the app couldn't recognise very well for exactly the same ID cards and passports. Then I've found it's after I updated iOS from iOS 16 to 17, and all the iOS 17 devices are getting very poor accuracy performance. Devices with iOS 16.4.1 are still doing very well, with very good accuracy and speed.

I have checked the API, and don't see anything related to the sudden worsen of accuracy.

I wonder if anyone else is experiencing the same issues or not. Maybe someone else knows why and can help me to solve the problems.

Thank you.

```
        let controller = DataScannerViewController(
                        recognizedDataTypes: [.text()],
                        qualityLevel: .accurate,
                        recognizesMultipleItems: true,
                        isHighFrameRateTrackingEnabled: true,
                        isGuidanceEnabled: false,
                        isHighlightingEnabled: true
                    )
```